# Django Tutorial and Sqlite command line

Tags: django, sqlite

I am going through the Django tutorial at
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/

It had said previously that if I use sqlite that I don't need to install anything.

Now, it says, after I migrate, ,"
 If you’re interested, run the command-line client for your database and type \dt (PostgreSQL), SHOW TABLES; (MySQL), .schema (SQLite), or SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES; (Oracle) to display the tables Django created.
"

Am I supposed to have a command line editor for sqlite already or do I need to go fetch something from the web? If the latter, what do I get? If the former, what is the command to start it up?

Comment: First you have to determine your underlying database. Second I propose to use all-in-one tool https://dbeaver.io/ that is able to any modern RDMBS that supports JDBC driver. The queries that you quoted are used to display metadata related to tables.

Comment: I'd like to use sqlite for now.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/cli.html - but I suggest to use GUI tool if you are new to RDBMSes

Comment: If you don't already have `sqlite3` on your computer, versions for a few OSes can be downloaded at https://sqlite.org/download.html (or get the source and build it yourself)

Comment: The tutorial just tells you how you can verify in the database that everything was done correctly. If you run `migrate` and everything worked, you don't need to do that. But if you're a database guy, you'll like to see the actual changes that were made to the db after you run `migrate`. In your terminal just type `sqlite3 /path/to/db.sqlite` and then you can run sql commands directly on your db.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have everything installed.

In your terminal, just type `sqlite3` to start the sqlite command-line tool. Then use `.help` to see all the available commands. You can `.open` your database or you can run `sqlite3 /path/to/db.sqlite` directly to run the tool with your django db already open.

With the command `.schema` you'll be able to see all your tables structure. But you can also directly run a `sql` command like `SELECT * FROM polls_question;`

Comment: sqlite3 is unrecognized, so it isn't installed or the path is not set.

Comment: It's installed somewhere otherwise django wouldn't be able to create a SQLite database and migrate it. What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: So, it isn't installed by default and i have to download the command line interface?

Comment: It's probably installed somewhere but not in your path ($Env:Path)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. on windows :

1. download `sqlite-tools` (there is separate `sqlite-tools` for each OS. download based on your OS.) from : https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
2. put 3 .exe files in : `C:\Program Files\sqlite3`
3. add `C:\Program Files\sqlite3` to windows PATH ENV Variable. ([click if you don't know how](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/test-runners/add-path-environment-variables))
4. you may now open `command prompt` and run:

`cd <DjangoProjectPath>`

`sqlite3 db.sqlite3`

Inside sqlite shell:
`.schema`

Now it works without any error.

Comment: anybody would know how to do on ubuntu ?